# Perl to Ruby conversion (multidimensional arrays)

Tags: ruby, perl, multidimensional-array

I'm just trying to get my head around a multidimensional array creation from a perl script i'm currently converting to Ruby, I have 0 experience in Perl, as in i opened my first Perl script this morning.

Here is the original loop:

```
my $tl = {};

for my $zoom ($zoommin..$zoommax) {

    my $txmin = lon2tilex($lonmin, $zoom);
    my $txmax = lon2tilex($lonmax, $zoom);
    # Note that y=0 is near lat=+85.0511 and y=max is near
    # lat=-85.0511, so lat2tiley is monotonically decreasing.
    my $tymin = lat2tiley($latmax, $zoom);
    my $tymax = lat2tiley($latmin, $zoom);

    my $ntx = $txmax - $txmin + 1;
    my $nty = $tymax - $tymin + 1;
    printf "Schedule %d (%d x %d) tiles for zoom level %d for download ...\n",
           $ntx*$nty, $ntx, $nty, $zoom
        unless $opt{quiet};
    $tl->{$zoom} = [];    

    for my $tx ($txmin..$txmax) {
        for my $ty ($tymin..$tymax) {
        push @{$tl->{$zoom}}, 
            { xyz => [ $tx, $ty, $zoom ] };
        }
    }

}
```

and what i have so far in Ruby:

```
  tl = []

  for zoom in zoommin..zoommax

    txmin = cm.tiles.xtile(lonmin,zoom)
    txmax = cm.tiles.xtile(lonmax,zoom)

    tymin = cm.tiles.ytile(latmax,zoom)
    tymax = cm.tiles.ytile(latmin,zoom)

    ntx = txmax - txmin + 1
    nty = tymax - tymin + 1

    tl[zoom] = []

    for tx in txmin..txmax
      for ty in tymin..tymax
        tl[zoom] << xyz = [tx,ty,zoom]
        puts tl
      end
    end

  end
```

The part i'm unsure of is nested right at the root of the loops, `push @{$tl->{$zoom}},{ xyz => [ $tx, $ty, $zoom ] };`

I'm sure this will be very simple for a seasoned Perl programmer, thanks! `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Perl code is building up a complex data structure in `$tl` -- hash, array, hash, array:

```
$tl{$zoom}[i]{xyz}[j] = $tx     # j = 0
$tl{$zoom}[i]{xyz}[j] = $ty     # j = 1
$tl{$zoom}[i]{xyz}[j] = $zoom   # j = 2
```

So I think the key line in your Ruby code should be like this:

```
tl[zoom] << { 'xzy' => [tx,ty,zoom] }
```

Note also that the root item (`$tl`) refers to a hash in the Perl code, while your Ruby code initializes it to be an array. That difference might cause problems for you, depending on the values that `$zoom` takes.

Comment: perfect thanks, the combination of hashes and arrays were causing me some confusion

Comment: Data::Dumper is your fried when dealing with complex structures. Just let it build $tl, and then: use Data::Dumper; die Dumper($tl);